# regex insert a word into a text in alphabetical order

Tags: ruby, regex, text-processing

I've implemented a ruby script which supposed to generate & insert a default code pieces into a right places. The problem is that some of those code pieces must respect alphabetical order of existed code.

As an example, assume that we need to insert a code piece for word **'thumb'** (in this case it would be `UPDATEFIELD((&(thumb)), ([custominputstream readString]));` ) into the following code:

```
    //...
    UPDATEFIELD((&(answers)), ((ListTO *)[custominputstream readCustomSerializable]));
    UPDATEFIELD((&(text)), ([custominputstream readString]));
    UPDATEFIELD((&(title)), ([custominputstream readString]));
    //...
```

The wished result is:

```
    //...
    UPDATEFIELD((&(answers)), ((ListTO *)[custominputstream readCustomSerializable]));
    UPDATEFIELD((&(text)), ([custominputstream readString]));
    UPDATEFIELD((&(thumb)), ([custominputstream readString]));  //here is the right place to do it.
    UPDATEFIELD((&(title)), ([custominputstream readString]));
    //...
```

The question is how to find this precise place for text insertion with regex / is it possible at all?

Comment: Show us what have you already tried.

Comment: @mudasobwa I haven't found anything related to my problem in docs, so there's nothing to show.

Comment: Programming is not about copy-pasting solutions from docs/SO, it is about solving problems.

Comment: @mudasobwa thank you so much, my wise friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your current order of words is

```
answers < text < title
```

An approach towards the problem can be reading the file from the top and breaking it at the center.

which in your case is

`UPDATEFIELD((&(text)), ([custominputstream readString]));`

read the

`/(?<=UPDATEFIELD\(\(&\()\w+(?=\))/` string 
which is nothing but `text`

and then compare it with your word. Which in your case happens to be `thumb`

```
if 'thumb' < 'text'
  #place it above text
else #(which is obvious) then 
  #place it below
end
```

the order becomes

```
answers < text < thumb < title
```

Your file is quite big, thus you may need to repeat the same exercise until you reach your goal.

we are doing a [binary search](https://blog.penjee.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/binary-and-linear-search-animations.gif) to reach the place where we need to insert our word.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick answer, seems like it's exactly what I need! Now I need some time to apply it, cause I'm a total noob both in regex and ruby; I'll write back + accept the answer asap :)

Comment: hmm... I can't get how to insert a line directly above/below the line with the match. Previously in such cases I've used this approach 
`def dataAppendTo(methodName, string, data, bottomEdge)
 return data.sub /(-.*#{methodName}.*\n)((.*\n)*?)(.*#{bottomEdge}.*)/, '\1\2' + string + '
\4'
end`

to insert new lines, but here it doesn't seem to be appliable.

Comment: I think one easy way to do it would be to read your file as a string and split on '\n' or '\n\r' and find the index of the word you want and insert a new word with `array.insert(index, word)` Hope this helps